# Ruby Shoes ssh connect

Tags: ruby, shoes

So I've added a button that on click calls function log_in

```
button "Login" do
  log_in
end
```

And this is my function, it's supposed to connect to a server with username and password

```
def log_in
  alert "Hola"
  Net::SSH.start(@hostname, 'Maria', :password => "mariahi") do |ssh|
    ssh.exec "ls" do |ch, success|
      para success
      if success then
        alert "yay"
      else
        alert "Fail"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I do get the first dialog alert, which means the function is called on click but nothing happens from there. Where's my mistake? Using Ruby Shoes.

Comment: Use more alerts (or a debugger, or `puts` statements, or whatever) to find out where the program is getting stalled.  You need to know whether it is successfully connecting, and if so, whether the remote "ls" is returning results.

Comment: Right, any tips on how to do it? I am fairly new to the whole thing.

Comment: You've already used an alert to confirm that the function was called on click.  Add another alert after the `Net::SSH.start` line to find out if the network connection was established, and another after the `ssh.exec "ls"` line to find out if the "ls" returned results.

Comment: The connection was established but ssh.exec "ls" gives no results. Rather, nothing happens, no error messages either.

Comment: That's good to know.  That information needs to be in the question itself--comments are ephemeral on SO.  Can you please click "edit" and add all the additional information you have to the question?  Then for the next experiment: Remove all of the "shoes" from the program, and make it just do the `SSH.start...` and `SSH.connect...` and see what happens.